# How many unique sets can at once be made from a bag of letters?

Tags: string, algorithm, combinations

**Summary:**

Let's say that I have got a bag of letters (a multiset), how many unique sets can I make at the same time? Multiple of the same letter can exist in the bag of letters and each instance can only be used once. (once a set as been made, the letter instances that compose it cannot be used again). Order of characters in the set does not matter.

There are two cases I am interested in.

1. The bag contains one of each letter
2. The bag contains the same amounts (a constant k > 1) of each letter.

I know that for case 1, I can make a maximum total of `n` unique sets (each set has only one letter) where n is the amount of different letters in the bag. How would I approach case 2? I need an algorithm to give me the list of sets when it is maximized.

Case 2 example:

Given: `{a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b}`
Answer: `[{a}, {b}, {ab}]`. `{a,a}` and `{b,b}` are invalid sets (has duplicates) and so are not included. `{a,b}` is already included in list and can't be added, so we have a remainder of `[a,a,b,b]`

**Motivation:**

In the popular video game *Minecraft*, there is a device called an [encoder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR66Ees_CTg) that takes an item and encodes it to a unique redstone code for use in encoded storage systems. It works by doing the equivalent of a `contains(item)` operation on multiple containers. Depending on which containers contain the item, different 'codes' are generated. However, since the largest container in the game (a double chest) has only 54 slots, it can only hold up to 54 different items. As a smaller encoder with less chests is desired, the encoder must be smart about how it maps the codes to fully leverage all the inventory spaces in the machine with a small footprint.

This application is equivalent to case 2a of the above. Consider each chest as a character, and a code as a set. Since each chest has 54 slots we model this situation with a bag of letters with 54 duplicate letters of each character. Given `n` chests, we would have `n * 54` letters in the bag. The goal is to find the maximum amount of unique sets possible from a certain number of chests `n`.

Comment: If you only accept real words then you may as well play Scrabble.

Comment: Are you looking for [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a counterexample to the following greedy algorithm? First we build `nCr(n, 1)`, then `nCr(n, 2)`, then `nCr(n, 3)`...etc. until we run out of letters.

Each set constructed is necessarily distinct from the previous ones, and since we're growing by one element each time, we exhaust the possibilities for each set size,  consuming as few letters as possible.

I believe we can construct a counterexample when the distribution of letters is uneven. Can someone provide one when it is even?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking of earlier, but I've got no guarantee it works 100% of the time.

Comment: @Andrew then it might be interesting to think of a proof :)